# Parse Javascript SDK - Query causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, sdk, parse-cloud-code

I have some Parse Cloud code that fetches and updates data in the Parse database.

```
app.get('/endpoint', function(request, response) {

    var username = "name";
    var something = "something";

    var userFetchQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userFetchQuery.equalTo("username", username);

    userFetchQuery.first().then(function(foundUser) {

       var fetchQuery = new Parse.Query("Call");
       fetchQuery.equalTo("initiator", foundUser);
       //fetchQuery.equalTo("status", 5); 
       return fetchQuery.first();

    }).then(function(currentObject) {
        var callObjectId = currentObject.id;
        currentCall.set("something", something);
        return currentCall.save(); 

    }).then(function(success) {
        response.send(ourResponse);
    }); 
 });
```

The code above works fine, however if I try to uncomment the line where I query the table by status (`fetchQuery.equalTo("status", 5);`), then I get the 500 internal error. Basically, I can't seem to query with both criteria (user and status).

Can't we have two `equalTo()` calls to the Parse.Query object? What could be wrong here?

**======== EDIT 1 ========**

If I query by both user and status, then I get no results back. If I query by just one of them, then I get data back. So, the question is: why are the two `equalTo()` statements causing the query to fail? I am 100% sure that I have appropriate data.

**======== EDIT 2 ========**

I have tried to isolate the issue by querying by any 2 fields of the table. Whenever there are two `equalTo()` statements, the query doesn't return anything. I have hardcoded the values for the `equalTo()` to make sure and result is always the same. Having more than one `equalTo()`s for Parse.Query() object results in 0 query results.

Comment: I think the issue is in `var fetchQuery = new Parse.Query("Call");`. the parameter should not be a `String`

Comment: Just tried changing it to a class created by `Parse.Object.extend()` but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you share the definition of the object type you are trying to query here?

Comment: Sure, do you want to see the fields? Is there an easy way to share the definition of a Parse Class? Also, please see my Edit 2.

Comment: I reffered to the below link and it is expected to be chainable method. Not able to understand th eroot cause here - {https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_equalTo}

Comment: Does it work if the `fetchQuery.equalTo("status", 5); ` is in its own callback?

Comment: What do you mean by 'in its own callback'? It works if we only have the status in the query (not the user).